# Android "google play music app". How force it play ONLY local songs on my phone

Tags: mobile-data, music-player, google-play-music

How to force "google play music app" play ONLY songs I paid for and downloaded to my phone.
In other words how to restrict it from contacting the web and using my data allocation.
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Press the hamburger button (top left) and enable "Downloaded Only".